# Soft question:Intuition for tangent space

Tags: soft-question, manifolds, intuition

I am trying to learn topology, from An introduction to manifolds of Loring W.Tu second edition to be precise, while I saw the definition of tangent space I don't think I understood what they are and what they mean, how would you explain the concept of tangent space in an informal manner.

Comment: Every $n$-manifold can be embedded in ${\mathbb R}^{2n+1}$ (in fact ${\mathbb R}^{2n}$, but $2n+1$ is quite easy to prove). Then "tangent space" can be viewed in the same way as you visualize the tangent plane of a $2$-surface in ${\mathbb R}^3$.

Comment: What does this have to do with derivations?

Comment: In my opinion, in a manifold $M$ we don't have an intrinsic coordinate, but we can still talk about different directions by detecting small changes of a function $f:M\to \mathbb R$ at $p\in M$ along different directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I give the notion as in Differential Geometry, other definitions of course exist:

For simplicity let us consider our manifold to be the surface of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which of course may be described as: S = $\{ a \in \mathbb{R^3} : ||a|| = 1\}$

$v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is a **tangent vector** of $S$ at $x \in S$ if there is a smooth curve, $\gamma:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow S$ s.t.

1. $\gamma(0) = x$
2. $\dot{\gamma}(0) = v $

The set of tangent vectors of $S$ at $x$, denoted $T_x(S)$ is given to be:
$$T_x(S) = \{\dot{\gamma}(0)| \gamma \textrm{ smooth,}\gamma(0) = x\}. $$

Say $x = (1,0,0)$  Then, intuitively, what would the tangent space be?
what will its dimension be?

The intuition we develop in 3 space will hold for $n$ space

Comment: 2(x-1)+2y+2z must be zero,

Comment: Therefore it must be 2 dimensional,

Comment: exactly, yes, and also note that we will have unaccountably many 'copies' of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as our collection of tangent spaces.  One at each point $x$ on our manifold.